# Mapping through icons with React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons, jsx

I need to map icons to my app bar.

It does not show anything. Once I try it the app bar component does not show any icons.

I am not sure how to map through a jsx component inside an array so I can show it in the app bar structure I already have.

-icons.js---------------

```
import { Download, GitHub, Mail, WhatsApp } from "@mui/icons-material";

export const icons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    ariaLabel: "whatsapp",
    tooltip: "Chat in whatsapp",
    icon: WhatsApp,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ariaLabel: "github",
    tooltip: "View github profile",
    icon: GitHub,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    ariaLabel: "mail",
    tooltip: "Write email",
    icon: Mail,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    ariaLabel: "curriculum vitae",
    tooltip: "Dowloand CV",
    icon: Download,
  },
];
```

-Appbar.jsx------------

```
<Appbar>
  {icons.map((Icon) => (
    <Box key={Icon.id} sx={{ mr: 10 }}>
      <Tooltip title={Icon.tooltip}>
        <IconButton aria-label={Icon.ariaLabel}>
          <Icon />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </Box>
  ))}
</Appbar>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after mapping icons  you can  access the name of your component icon like this  `<Icon.icon />` . So just change  `<Icon />` to  `<Icon.icon />` .

this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-9x87n8?file=/demo.js) to show you

Answer (score 0):

```
<Appbar>
{icons.map((Icon) => {
return(
<Box key={Icon.id} sx={{ mr: 10 }}>
<Tooltip title={Icon.tooltip}>
  <IconButton aria-label={Icon.ariaLabel}>
    <Icon />
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
</Box>
)})}
</Appbar>;
```

Comment: console error is showing : ` Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Answer (score 0):

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-ben-c0is7b?file=/src/Components/Function.jsx:610-763) <== The answer would be like

```
 <div>
  {icons.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      {item.tooltip}
      <item.icon />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the difference is that I was using **react-icons library instead of mui**. For my case the icon was a JSX element(icon: `<Whatsapp/>`) in the file icons.js so I changed the file extension e.g *icons.js to icons.jsx* and it worked out(the icons were rendered successfully)in the Appbar.jsx.
You can compare analogously!